# Manga where the main character kills the Demon Lord (as well as his own friends)

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The main character kills the Demon Lord at last but is forced to do it again as his evaluation comes to be F.

He killed his own friends because they were really slow. And he is evaluated by the God or someone who tells him that he is not Ideal Hero, so he should start again, sending him back in time.

Comment: This is very terse. Does he kill the Demon Lord's friends or his own? Who is the main character and who is he being evaluated by?

Comment: He killed his own friends because they were really slow. And he is evaluated by the God or someone who tells him that he is not Ideal Hero, so he should start again sending him back in time.

Comment: This sounds very similar to [Tsuyokute New Saga](https://myanimelist.net/manga/74283/Tsuyokute_New_Saga)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are looking for [FFF-Class Trashero](https://mangadex.cc/title/41652/fff-class-trashero).

The first chapter has the hero slaying the demon king, then a goddess come to him with a report card.  He has an F rank in personality, so he is sent back in time so he can improve his score.  The report card also has the remark "WHY DID YOU KILL YOUR PERFECTLY SANE COMRADES?"